# Can one give Tzeddakah retroactively?

Tags: tzedakah-charity

If I gave more than 10% charity in a previous month, may I apply the surplus towards future months?

Comment: Even if it doesn't you can just arrange with the Tzedaka to give them a loan and then forgive the loan at a later date when you get more money.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67353/11501

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can decide yourself the period on which you count tsedaka. Typical approaches are from Rosh Hashana to Rosh Hashana, or from January to December (so you know how much taxes you will pay).

Even from year to year you can use "credits" from over donating in previous years. Remember most consider tsedaka a very worthwhile minhag, not a strict halacha (see beginning of [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67389/11501))

Both R Avrohom Chaim Feuer in [The tsedakka treasury](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1578195144) 
and R Shimon Taub's in [The laws of tsedakah and maaser](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578195893.html)) **allow *yearly accounting* of once's maaser, i.e., you do not need to give maaser as income arrives as long as you "clear the account" regularly**. This is also the allowance of **The Chofetz Chaim** (in Ahavas Chesed 18:2).

As I wrote [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67389/11501), the Chofetz Chaim offers the following guidance on setting up a maaser system (with personal additions to make it practical to the 21st century)

1. Set up a separate ledger (or a spreadsheet) to track earnings, any business expenses, taxes and donations
2. Designate a specific date (e.g., Rosh Hashana) to mark the end of an accounting period where you "close the books" - should be at least once a year - can be more frequent
3. At the time of the closing period, calculate profits, deduct losses and acceptable expenses and the amount of maaser
4. Deduct all donations already made and distribute immediately whatever you owe (i.e., the difference between maaser and previous donations)
5. If you have given more than your planned maaser, some authorities allow to carry over to the next accounting period. Even those that are strict allow it if you stipulate (orally) that you may deduct from your maaser obligations at all times any donations you make at any time you desire

Answer (score 0):

I think the halacha is that the obligation to give *Ma'aser* (10%)  applies when one gets a unit of money i.e a paycheck. Once one obtains the money, in order to use it for his own personal needs he must give 10% of the money he has now.

I don't have sources off hand though.

Comment: This is not correct, one doesn't have to give 10% of the money one has before using the rest. At best, you can say one should set aside the 10% (e.g., mentally, by tracking it or in a separate account). Also remember most consider tsedaka a very worthwhile minhag, not a strict halacha

Comment: @mbloch be careful not to mix up maaseh k'sofim and tzedakah

Comment: @Orangesandlemons thanks! I was speaking of maaser ksafim indeed, like the OP

Answer (score 0):

You confuse Maaser and Zedaka (charity):

- Zedaka is practically unlimited and not refundable. You can give any amount to anyone anytime.
- Maaser is a sort of "10% tax" on your net income. Opinions differ, but most hold that once you **knowingly** give more than 10%, the surplus is counted as a Zedaka, not as a future Maaser, as one can not pay taxes for future income.