# Segulah for Parnasah

Tags: tzedakah-charity, segulah, parnassah-livelihood

In the new Rabbi Meir Zlotowitz Biography (page 276) they quote Rabbi Zlotowitz once saying that "Giving tzedakah as if you are rich - is the greatest segulah  to actually get there".

What was his source for this?

Comment: עשר בשביל שתתעשר

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93701/759

Comment: conversely  המבזבז אל יבזבז יותר מחומש שמא יצטרך לבריות

Comment: @Loewian So what IS Pshat?

Comment: Perhaps he just meant that even 1/10-1/5 is generally done by the wealthy; and that those of moderate means should still give accordingly as if they were wealthy, but still following chazal's rule.